# How to direct (Python) error messages printed in a PowerShell console to a text file

Tags: command-line, windows-10, powershell, python

Firstly, the errors I'm interested in redirecting are NOT PowerShell errors, but those generated by a Python script that is called within my PowerShell script. I have read multiple post on here (and other StackExchange sites, Windows PowerShell scripting guy article, and various other locations. This has lead me to develop the script as it is below, but the output is somewhat odd.

```
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"

$SnapsToTest = Get-ChildItem C:\Snaps\ -Directory
$ErrorFile = "C:\Tools\Scripts\Errors.txt"
$SnapDir = "C:\Logs"
$LogDir = "\var\log\"
$LogFile = "support.log"
$env:PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8"

Start-Transcript -path $ErrorFile
Push-Location
Set-Location -Path $SnapDir

$SnapsToTest | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host $_.Name
        python C:\Tools\Scripts\script1.py $_.Name
        $LogToTest = $_.Name+$LogDir+$LogFile
        python C:\Tools\Scripts\script2.py $LogToTest
    }

Pop-Location
Stop-Transcript
```

Now, if I run script using `.\myscript.ps1 > output.text` I almost get what I'm after, but not quite.

I end up with two files, `output.text` and `errors.txt`.

The Output Text shows all the output generated by the Python script. The Errors Text file shows SOME of the output written to the screen, but not if the Python script crashes an writes out its stack trace, however I DO see this in the terminal, and this I do not understand.

For example, the output I see in the error text file is:

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20160429160228
Username: PC\me
RunAs User: PC\me
Machine: PC(Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14328.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Process ID: 16844
PSVersion: 5.1.14328.1000
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.14328.1000
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion: 10.0.14328.1000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
SnapDir1
SnapDir2
SnapDir3
```

However, what I see in the console is:

```
C:\Tools\Scripts> .\myscript.ps1 | Out-File output.txt
SnapDir1
SnapDir2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Tools\Scripts\script1.py", line 446, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1])
  File "C:\Tools\Scripts\script1.py", line 436, in main
    dba = DBAnalyser(rootdir)
  File "C:\Tools\Scripts\script1.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.osstatus = self._read_osstatus(osstatus_file)
  File "C:\Tools\Scripts\script1.py", line 170, in _read_osstatus
    ret[hostname]["meminfo"] = { "memtotal": memtotal, "memfree": memfree}
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'memtotal' referenced before assignment
SnapDir3
```

I can't see how to get the above error I see in the PowerShell console to show in the Errors.txt file

This is running in Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: you could wrap all code inside a scriptblock and redirect your output like this: `&{ # your whole code in here } 2>&1 | out-file C:\somepath\error.txt` however, I'm not sure if there's a better solution for this.

Comment: I also posted this to the Scripting Guy forums, and although I had read about the various redirections within PowerShell, it didn't seem to make much sense to me (and to be honest it still doesn't), but instead I invoked the script by using `.\myscript.ps1 > output.txt 2>errors2.txt`, and I kinda end up with what I want. This gives 3 files, the `errors2.txt` only contain the Python errors, but not the `error.txt` file created by `Start-Transcript` give both the output of `Write-Host` and the Python script error. The only small glitch is I no longer see the Python errors in the console